# Data inserted into a database when refresh page in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Form cache my input and insert it when refresh page how can I stop it
and should I use CodeIgniter validation or can use mine?

view:

```
 <html>
 <head></head>
</body>
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>  
 <?php echo form_open('speed/insert_to_db'); ?>
 Branch: <input type="text" name="branch" /><br/>
Business Unit: <input type="text" name="buinessUnit" /><br/>
Device Type: <input type="text" name="deviceType" /><br/>
Brand: <input type="text" name="brand" /><br/>
Device Model: <input type="text" name="deviceModel" /><br/>
SN: <input type="text" name="SN" /><br/>
status: <input type="text" name="status" /><br/>
department: <input type="text" name="department" /><br/>
username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br/>
notes: <input type="textarea" name="notes" /><br/>
computername: <input type="text" name="computerName" /><br/>
Save:<input type="submit" name="save" />

</form>
```

controller:

```
class Speed extends CI_Controller {

        function insert_to_db()
           {
               //$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
             $this->load->model('add_model');
             $this->add_model->insert_into_db();
             $this->load->view('pages/home');//loading success view
           }


}
```

model:to insert data in to database

```
<?php
class add_model extends CI_Model {

       public function insert_into_db(){
           $post=$this->input->post();
           if(!isset($post['save'])) return;
           $data=array('Branch'=>$post['branch'],'BusinessUnit'=>$post['buinessUnit'],'DeviceType'=>$post['deviceType'],'Brand'=>$post['brand'],'DeviceModel'=>$post['deviceModel'],'SN'=>$post['SN'],'Status'=>$post['status'],'Departmant'=>$post['department'],'UserName'=>$post['username'],'Notes'=>$post['notes'],'ComputerName'=>$post['computerName']);
           $this->db->insert('hardware_assets', $data);
return $this->db->insert_id(); // if using mysql
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a random number like this code below for controller,

```
$rand = rand( 100000, 999999);
$data['rand'] = $rand;
$this->session->set_userdata('form_hash',$rand);
```

while first controller call, and pass the same to form in hidden variable like in view,

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_hash" value="<?php echo $rand?>" />
```

so, every time a controller gets called you compare the number if it is same, if validation passes, go ahead, if not, do not insert the data.

```
if($this->input->post('form_hash') == $this->session->userdata('form_hash'))
{
    // process with database entry
}
```

Note that those two hashes will only match once, while submitting the form first time, every other time, the if condition will fail.

So, your final code will be like this,

```
class Speed extends CI_Controller
{
    function insert_to_db()
    {
        $this->load->model('add_model');

        if($this->input->post('form_hash') == $this->session->userdata('form_hash'))
        {
            $this->add_model->insert_into_db();
        }
        $rand = rand( 100000, 999999);
        $data['rand'] = $rand;
        $this->session->set_userdata('form_hash',$rand);

        //loading success view
        $this->load->view('pages/home', $data);
    }
}
```

and don't forget to insert this line in your view inside form,

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_hash" value="<?php echo $rand?>" />
```